# How to pass paired argument to summaryM function test in Hmisc [r]

Tags: r, hmisc

I have reproducible example here

```
library(Hmisc)
set.seed(173)
sex <- factor(sample(c("m","f"), 500, rep=TRUE))
country <- factor(sample(c('US', 'Canada'), 500, rep=TRUE))
age <- rnorm(500, 50, 5)
sbp <- rnorm(500, 120, 12)
label(sbp) <- 'Systolic BP'
units(sbp) <- 'mmHg'
treatment <- factor(rep(c("PreTretment","PostTretment"), 250))

f <- summaryM(age + sex + sbp ~ treatment, test=TRUE)
```

SummaryM function from Hmisc package has test argument which as default applies Wilcoxon test to continues variable assuming they are independent. Now I would like to pass `paired=TRUE` to Wilcoxon. How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: But, but, but, ... the data are not paired. How could they be? They have different counts. Once you solve that question then why not pre-calculate a difference on the variables of interest for paired cases and (perhaps) then use (n.b. untested notion) `summaryM` to give you the paired test (which is really just a test against an H0 = 0 for the differences. See Details section in `?wilcox.test`

Comment: @BondedDust I have added simplified version. Could you comment on this one?

Comment: I tried making a `conTest` object modeled  after conTestkw, but I do not think that paired comparisons should be passed to summaryM. I think that `summary.formula` is the proper method to do paired tests and I have a working example. Unfortunately despite constructing a method that delivers the correct statistic, it fails to print because of an error with the `pval` that I cannot track down.

Comment: @BondedDust thanks for effort. SummaryM is the new version of old summary.formula but only reverse method. All the remaining are equal in this two functions. I think Harrell uses some kind of internal Wilcoxon method, it is not wilcox.test generic method of stats package.

Comment: Huh, that might explain some of the apparent errors in the documentation for summaryM then.

Answer (score 1):

My current effort at making a paired Wilcoxon test with Hmisc summary methods:

```
 conTestWP <- 
function (group, x) 
{
    st <- wilcox.test( x[as.numeric(group)==1], x[as.numeric(group)==2], paired=TRUE)
    list(P = st["p.value"], stat = st["statistic"], df = st[c("df1", "df2")], 
        testname = "Wilcoxon-paired",
        statname = "V", latexstat = "V", plotmathstat = "F[df]")}
```

The summaryM method splits its grouping variables and is therefore not appropriate for paired tests. The `summary.formula` set of methods does allow a "reverse" method where the continuous variable is on the RHS of the formula:

```
f <- summary.formula(treatment ~ sbp, data=dat, method="reverse", 
                      test=TRUE,conTest=conTestWP)
```

Trying to print `f` throws an error (claiming falsely that the p-value is not numeric) but you can look inside to see that the paired `wilcox.test` results were passed into the object and the are the same as if you had done them "by hand":

```
 str(f) # but did snip some of the output:

 $ testresults:List of 1
  ..$ sbp:List of 7
  .. ..$ P           :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ p.value: num 0.589
  .. ..$ stat        :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ NA: NULL
  .. ..$ df          :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ NA: NULL
  .. .. ..$ NA: NULL
  .. ..$ testname    : chr "Wilcoxon-paired"
  .. ..$ statname    : chr "V"
  .. ..$ latexstat   : chr "V"
  .. ..$ plotmathstat: chr "F[df]"
```

Efforts to fix the error that gets thrown by putting in hard-coded numbers for the "df" values are failing. I have not succeeding in following the traceback which I paste in only the top of:

```
> f
Error in log10(ifelse(pv > 0, pv, 1e-50)) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
> traceback()
5: format.pval(pval, digits = pdig, eps = eps)
4: formatTestStats(tr, prtest = prtest, latex = latex, testUsed = testUsed, 
       pdig = pdig, eps = eps, footnoteTest = footnoteTest)
3: formatCons(stats[[i]], nam, tr, x$group.freq, prmsd, sep, formatArgs, 
       round, prtest, pdig = pdig, eps = eps)
2: print.summary.formula.reverse(list(stats = list(sbp = c(97.9191028465814, 
   94.9839938500064, 100.014783572809, 97.2881910017715, 107.288034416825, 
   105.746587052709, 111.864782483651, 112.689945667021, 116.229748640414, 
   115.604190135259, 119.743427097173, 119.276780441804, 123.380695706571, 
   122.111672516175, 128.138778071723, 126.592782661592, 133.726823015259, 
   132.141219449201, 140.847941698775, 136.762891898923, 145.175812916341, 
   141.635692905295, 120.013464038065, 118.994407752318, 12.1494617994813, 
   11.9252958974706)), type = 2, group.name = "treatment", group.label = "treatment",
```

Answer (score 0):

that works for me:

```
conTestWP <- 
function (group, x) 
{
    st <- wilcox.test( x[as.numeric(group)==1], x[as.numeric(group)==2], paired=TRUE)
    list(P=st$p.value, stat=st$statistic, df = "NA", 
    testname = "Wilcoxon-paired",
    statname = "V", namefun = "fstat", latexstat = "V", plotmathstat = "F[df]")}
```